# Rake CLEAN/CLOBBER not deleting

Tags: ruby, rake

I think I'm going mad. Can anyone help?

I have the folder c:\project\bin
I run the following to execute my rake script

```
cd C:\project
rake
```

In my rake script I have:

```
require 'rake/clean'
CLOBBER.include('bin')

task :default => [:compile]

task :compile do
    # do nothing
end
```

It doesn't delete the "bin" folder nor the contents of the "bin" folder. I'm running Ruby in Windows (1.86 or so) and installed rake using, gem install rake.

Have I missed something. I've tried --trace etc.. but get no feedback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR: `$ rake clobber`

---

As the answer above said, they are not implicilty invoked. Here is an example, as you asked for.

```
~/deleteme$ cd project
total 8
-rw-r--r--@ 1 josh  staff  110 Jun 27 06:04 Rakefile


~/deleteme/project$ cat Rakefile
require 'rake/clean'
CLOBBER.include('bin')

task :default => ["compile"]

task :compile do
  mkdir 'bin'
end


~/deleteme/project$ rake
(in /Users/josh/deleteme/project)
mkdir bin


~/deleteme/project$ ls -l
total 8
-rw-r--r--@ 1 josh  staff  110 Jun 27 06:04 Rakefile
drwxr-xr-x  2 josh  staff   68 Jun 27 06:05 bin


~/deleteme/project$ rake -T
(in /Users/josh/deleteme/project)
rake clean    # Remove any temporary products.
rake clobber  # Remove any generated file.


~/deleteme/project$ rake clobber
(in /Users/josh/deleteme/project)
rm -r bin


~/deleteme/project$ ls -l
total 8
-rw-r--r--@ 1 josh  staff  110 Jun 27 06:04 Rakefile
```

Answer (score 2):

CLEAN nor CLOBBER are not implicit tasks - you must declare dependency or invoke them

Comment: Could you give an example, as everywhere I'm reading doesn't state this to be the case. Martin Fowler for example, http://martinfowler.com/articles/rake.html#BuiltInCleaning, or this article http://www.stuartellis.eu/articles/rake/.

Answer (score 0):

For an easier way to do it, try

```
task :default => [:compile, :clobber]
```

instead of

```
task :default => ["compile"]
```

And then in your command-line you can just run

```
rake
```

Remember, in Ruby it is preferred to use Symbols instead of String literals